# If $s(x)= \int \sqrt{1+ \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2} dx$, what is $x(s)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

$s(x)$ is the formula for arc length of a function $f(x)=y$.

In the book I'm studying, curvature is defined as the instantaneous rate of change of direction (inclination of angle $\theta$) with respect to arc length, where $\theta = \arctan\big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big) $, all of which makes sense to me.

In order to find the curvature function, or $\frac{d\theta}{ds}$, the author goes:

$$\frac{d\theta}{ds} = \frac{d}{ds} \left(\arctan\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right)$$

Followed by: Since $\theta$ is a function of $x$, to get $\frac{d\theta}{ds}$ we have to use the chain rule:

$$\frac{d\theta}{ds} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)\right) \cdot \frac{dx}{ds}$$

where $$\frac{dx}{ds} = \frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dx}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \big(\frac{dy}{dx}\big)^2}}$$

All of this makes sense, even intuitively to some extent. However, I'm unsatisfied by the "skipping" of the original function.

In other words, **I'd like to have an expression for** $\theta(s)$, from which I could directly take the derivative $\frac{d\theta}{ds}$.

But I can't figure out how to do it and I get lost between all of the different functions and how they interact, and I think my main problem is that I have no idea how to get an expression for $x(s)$

Comment: One doesn't need to have an explicit expression for $x(s)$.  We use the fact that $$\frac{dx}{ds}=\frac{1}{\frac{ds}{dx}}$$And as you wrote, $\frac{ds}{dx}=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simplify the expression for $\frac{d\theta}{ds}$,

you will see $$\kappa=\frac{f''}{(1+(f')^2)^{3/2}}$$

If you want to find the expression explicitly for $\phi(s)=\theta(x(s))$, you see $\theta(x)=arctan(\frac{dy}{dx})$, you will need to find $x(s)$, which is a function that takes in arclength and output the value of x.

To find it, you will need arclength parametrization. Assume the function starts at $x=a$ and be defined for $x\geq a$, let  $\bar{r}(x)$ be a vector function and $\bar{r}(x)=(x,f(x))$
And
$$s(x)=\int_a^x|\bar{r}'(t)|dt=\int_a^x \sqrt{1+f'^2}dt$$ is a function of arclength

Let $F(x)$ be the antiderivative of $$\int \sqrt{1+f'^2}dx$$ (which may or may not exist),

Then $F(x)-F(a)=s(x)$,
$$s(x)+F(a)=F(x)$$

$$F^{-1}(s+F(a))=x(s)$$ since F(x) must be bijective (but may not have a close form)

So by using this construction you can define $x(s)$ (know as arc length paramrtrization/ natural parametrization) to find $\theta(x(s))=\phi(s)=arctan(f'(x(s))$

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. As far as you know, is there any other way whatsoever to derive $\theta(x)$?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff It is always possible to write down $\theta(x)$ explicitly in terms of x if $f(x)$ is given. BUT the angle function in terms of arclength $\theta(x(s))$ may not exist in close form(expressible in elementary functions) although theoretically it should always exist.The reason that it may not be expressible is because firstly the arclwngth function may not be integrable (in simple functions), secondly the inverse function $x(s)$ may not be expressible. (E.g. $s(x)=e^x+logx$ defined on $x\in(1,5)$, the function is bijective and thus is invertible,but it doesn't have a close form.)

Comment: @jeremyradcliff You will learn more about these when you get into differential geometry. It will get interesting and fun ;)

Comment: I can't wait! I wasn't into math at all when I was younger; I started studying it for CS but now I like it more and more on its own merits. Thanks for the details, it makes more sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

In differential geoemetry, most of the calculation needs you parametrize the curve by arclength. This means you have to reparametrize your curve such that it has unit speed.

In this case, your curve can be thought as: $\gamma(x):[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2:x\mapsto(x,f(x))$. It doesn't have the unit speed, so we have to reparametrize the curve by a new parameter say $s$ with $\gamma(x(s)):[c,d]\mapsto\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $|\gamma'(x)x'(s)|=1$. The   parameter $s$ may not unique, but it has to satisfy the condition $|\gamma'(x)x'(s)|=1$. This is why your book let $s(x)=\int_a^x\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx$ since it's easy to check this condition is satisfied.

So if you really want to write $\theta$ as a function of $s$. It should be something like this $\theta(x(s))=\arctan f'(x(s))$. You know $x$ is a function of $s$ and $|x'(s)|=1/|\gamma'(x)|=1/\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I don't know about differential geometry yet, but this is very interesting.